# How to trigger touchstart on a shape in a canvas?

Tags: events, mobile, canvas, touch, shapes

I have a canvas with some shapes in it. So, the functionality I'm making is: press some of the shapes, then I'm creating a HTML element who looks the same way and place it over the shape itself, and then, when you start moving the mouse - without releasing the mouse button - this new HTML element starts to drag. (Cause I can't directly drag shapes from canvas all over.)

BUT - it has to work on mobile devices (iPAd mostly), and I don't know to trigger such event there. The colleague that made the shapes drawing used EaselJS, and when I inspect a shape it has only onPress, onClick, onMouseOver, onMouseOut and onMouseMove events.

But the onPress doesn't trigger on iPad. I have only onClick there, which doesn't help me. And if I try with onTouchStart - it never triggers :(

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to workaround the situation :)

So, I made handlers for touchstart and touchmove on the canvas element in it, and when the touchstart triggers - then I'm looping through the shapes in the canvas and compare the coordinates of each shape with the coordinates of the touch event. So, this way I know which shape the user has touched.

A dump solution ... actually it' more like a hack ... but it works :) ...

Hope this helps someone else ;)